# Kubernetes NodePort connection refused

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos, load-balancing

I have a cluster with 3 nodes in virtualbox environment. I created cluster with flag

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

then I installed flannel and added rest of two nodes to the cluster. After that, new virtual machine was created to host private repository for docker images. Next, I used this .yaml to create deployment of my app:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gunicorn
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gunicorn
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gunicorn
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: my-registry-key
      containers:
      - name: ipcheck2
        image: 192.168.2.4:8083/ipcheck2:1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command:
        - sleep
        - "infinity"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 8080
```

image was created from following dockerfile and pushed to the repo:

```
FROM python:3

EXPOSE 8080

ADD /IP_check/ /

WORKDIR /

RUN pip install pip --upgrade

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["gunicorn", "IP_check.wsgi", "-b :8080"]
```

At this moment I can tell that If I run container from docker engine end expose this port I am able to connect with app.

Next I created NodePort service for my app:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ipcheck
spec:
  selector:
    app: gunicorn
  ports:
  - port: 70
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30000
  type: NodePort
```

And here is the issue. I checked with kubectl describe pods, which node is running pod with my app. Then I tried to use curl :30000 to reach the app but it doesn't work.

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.2.3:30000; Connection refused
```

Also I installed hello-world app from [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/) and exposed it with NodePort. This didn't work too.

Anyone has idea why I can't reach pod from inside cluster and from outside cluster with NodePort?

OS: Centos7

IP addresses:

```
Node1 192.168.2.1   -   Master
Node2 192.168.2.2   -   Worker
Node3 192.168.2.3   -   Worker
Node4 192.168.2.4   -   Private repo (outside of cluster)
```

Pod describe:

```
Name:         gunicorn-5f7f485585-wjdnf
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         node3/192.168.2.3
Start Time:   Thu, 16 Jul 2020 18:01:54 +0200
Labels:       app=gunicorn
              pod-template-hash=5f7f485585
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.1.20
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.1.20
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/gunicorn-5f7f485585
Containers:
  ipcheck2:
    Container ID:  docker://9aa18f3fff1d13dfc76355dde72554fd3af304435c9b7fc4f7365b4e6ac9059a
    Image:         192.168.2.4:8083/ipcheck2:1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://192.168.2.4:8083/ipcheck2@sha256:e48469c6d1bec474b32cd04ca5ccbc057da0377dff60acc37e7fa786cbc39526
    Port:          8080/TCP
    Host Port:     8080/TCP
    Command:
      sleep
      infinity
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 16 Jul 2020 18:01:55 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-9q77c (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-9q77c:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-9q77c
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  40m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/gunicorn-5f7f485585-wjdnf to node3
  Normal  Pulling    40m   kubelet, node3     Pulling image "192.168.2.4:8083/ipcheck2:1"
  Normal  Pulled     40m   kubelet, node3     Successfully pulled image "192.168.2.4:8083/ipcheck2:1"
  Normal  Created    40m   kubelet, node3     Created container ipcheck2
  Normal  Started    40m   kubelet, node3     Started container ipcheck2
```

Service describe:

```
Name:                     ipcheck
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              Selector:  app=gunicorn
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.111.7.129
Port:                     <unset>  70/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30000/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.1.20:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Node3 iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  10.244.0.0/16        anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.244.0.0/16

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* default/gunicorn-ipcheck: has no endpoints */ ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL tcp dpt:30384 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-PROXY-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.104.59.152        /* default/gunicorn-ipcheck: has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:webcache reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.2.240        /* default/gunicorn-ipcheck: has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:webcache reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

'ip a' on Node3:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a4:1d:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 86181sec preferred_lft 86181sec
    inet6 fe80::1272:64b5:b03b:2b75/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:14:7f:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.3/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2704:2b92:cc02:e88/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:a1:17:41:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 6e:c6:9c:0f:ab:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.244.1.0/32 scope global flannel.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6cc6:9cff:fe0f:ab55/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: cni0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:66:88:71:56:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.244.1.1/24 scope global cni0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4866:88ff:fe71:566a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth0ded1d29@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master cni0 state UP group default
    link/ether 22:c2:6b:c7:cc:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::20c2:6bff:fec7:cc7a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Endpoints:

```
ipcheck            10.244.1.21:8080   51m
kubernetes         192.168.2.1:6443   9d
```

Comment: What you mean by `At this moment I can tell that If I run container from docker engine end expose this port I am able to connect with app.`? It works with docker run? Could you try to deploy ClusterIP [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/) and check if it works internally?

Comment: Yes, when I use docker run I'm able to reach application. I tried to deploy this example. I applied yaml with nginx deploy. Pods IP looked similarly. Then I created service from given yaml. Describe svc looked similarly too. I tried to curl <ClusterIP>:<port>, but again it froze terminal and after some time I got Connection timed out.

Comment: I would say is either centos or virtual box network issue. Take a look [here](https://medium.com/@ErrInDam/taming-kubernetes-for-fun-and-profit-60a1d7b353de) how they configured centos and virtualbox network to make it work, maybe you find something that blocks you here. As far as I understand all of your pods are running and healthy?

Comment: I just found out (by accident ofc) why nodePort is not working, or why I can't reach pod when service works fine. Actually I forgot to delete 'sleep' command from deploy manifest, so container started gunicorn and then It went sleep which means that gunicorn was stoped by 'sleep'. However, thanks a lot everyone for help. (By the way, It is strange that I could not even reach pod from example)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you are able to curl using clusterip internally using
<curl [http://10.111.7.129:70>](http://10.111.7.129:70%3E)

Seems like the port is not open. Try opening the port 30000 at virtual box level/ if using AKS or IBM cloud open the port at security groups.

<firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port 30000/tcp>

Then use <curl http://workernodeIP:30000>

Thanks
VB

Comment: <curl http://10.111.7.129:70> is not working for me, I used it from all nodes and it freez terminal. I had truned off firewalld, but I added this rule and still nothing.